# Replacing of TestCafe async / await with promises

Tags: javascript, promise, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

For some reasons, I am trying to replace TestCafe Async / Await with Promises. Below is the chunk of code where I used the promises in place of await.

But getting an error like: A call to an async function is not awaited. Use the "await" keyword before actions, assertions or chains of them
      to ensure that they run in the right sequence.[image]

Comment: That means your test is asyncronous, but it's not declared as such. Just take an [official example of an async test](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/test-code-structure.html#test-controller) and replicate it, otherwise testcafe will be unable to understand whether the test is sync or async.

Comment: Try to return the `promise`

Comment: Images of [code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) and [exceptions](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/) aren't very helpful.

Comment: Could you please clarify why you want to replace async functions with Promises?

Comment: async functions return promises … so replacing them with promises is a very odd idea.

Comment: Thanks to all for the quick response :  1) i will try with by returning the promise . 2) Our application use promises everywhere in the source code hence we want to use the promise in our test script .     3) code : mport { selector } from "testcafe"

fixture `My fixure`
    .page `http://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/example`;


test("Test with promise", t => {
    let promise = new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve(t);
    });
    promise.then(result => {
    const data = result.typeText("#developer-name", "Yuvaraj");
    console.log(data);
    });
});

Comment: So `result.typeText(…)` returns a promise?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use `async/await`, you can return a Promise from the test function:

```js
fixture `Example`
    .page `example.com`;

test(`example`, t => {
   let promise = Promise.resolve(t);

   return promise
       .then(result => {
           return result.typeText('...');
       })
       .then(result => {
           return result.click('...');
       });
});
```

Comment: this solution perfectly working for me. thanks a lot. ( sorry for delay in response ).